# Find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{n^2} \: x^{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

This is a problem from the book of Kaczor & Nowak (Version II).
In the hint part, they find the radius of convergence by calculating the limsup of $(2^{n^2})^{1 \over n!}$. But I am unable to understand why not limsup of $(2^{n^2})^{1 \over n}$? 
Can anybody please tell me how to find the radius of convergence of this kind of power series where the power of $x$ is not $n$ (or power of $x$ is an injective function of $n$) with a rigorous analytical argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write the power series in the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$. In this case we have

$$a_n = \begin{cases}
2^{k^2},  & \text{if $n = k!$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

so

$$\frac1{R} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} {a_n}^{\frac1n} = \limsup_{k\to\infty} {a_{k!}}^{\frac1{k!}} = \limsup_{k\to\infty} {\left(2^{k^2}\right)}^{\frac1{k!}} = \limsup_{k\to\infty} 2^{\frac{k^2}{k!}} = 1$$

because we took the limsup of the only nontrivial subsequence of ${a_n}^{\frac1n}$, which is ${a_{k!}}^{\frac1{k!}}$ .

Answer (score 1):

Well, $x^{n!} = 2^{n!\log(x)}$ which for $x<1$ is $2^{-an!}$ for some positive $a(x)=a$ that is independent of $n$.

Note that for any such $a$, the function $an!$ dominates $n^2$ for $n$ large.

MEanwhile 0 raised to any positive power is 0.

Furthermore, one can check that if the sum converges for $x \in [0,1)$ then it also converges for $-x$.

On the other hand, $n!$ is even for all $n \geq 2$. So clearly this diverges for $x=-1$. (And clearly this diverges for $x \ge 1$.)

So the sum converges for all $x \in (-1,1)$. Thus the radius of convergence is 1.

Comment: The radius of convergence is obvious given the interval. The person asking the question should be able to convert partial answers that solve the crux of the problem, to precisely what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $|x|\ge 1$

$$|2^{n^2} \: x^{n!}|\to\infty$$

for $|x|< 1$ let $y=\frac 1 x$

$$\left|\frac{2^{n^2}}{y^{n!}}\right|\to0$$

and $\sum \frac{2^{n^2}}{y^{n!}}$ converges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac 1 {n^2}$.

Then the radius of convergence is $R=1$.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes of course! I should refer to the interval...Thanks, fixed.